# What is the best way to present multiple options in a form for section 508?

Tags: section508

I will need to provide a way for a user (who will be using a screen reader) to select multiple options within a form. Currently, these options are laid out in a two column table with checkboxes in the first column and `span`s with the `label` for the option in the second column. This isn't section 508 compliant, but it will need to be for this site. I'm trying to figure out the best way to replace this form with something better.

The options I have are to either

1. Use `ul`/`li`s with `label`s for the checkboxes

OR

1. Use a multi-select drop down list.

Does anyone have a preference or a better idea?

Comment: You can't use a multi-select, since it is not possible to select multiple options without the mouse.

Comment: I can select multiple options using a keyboard actually.

Comment: Non-contiguous selections? That's news to me. It must be something the newer browsers are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use a muli-select dropdown. In case anyone was wondering. It seems to work fairly well with the screen reader I'm using. I did find that IE seems to be the best browser to work with and most screen readers aren't working very well with Chrome or other browsers unfortunately. I can only assume then that most people who visually disabled are probably using IE because of this.